# Significance test of model performance

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, neural-networks, cross-validation

I have a data set with 350,000 entries and three models: a feedforward neural network, a recurrent neural network and a LSTM. To determine how well each model performs I used K-fold cross validation with k = 8. The error metric that I preferably use is the median absolute percentage error (MdAPE) (because of the presence of very large outliers) or otherwise the mean absolute percentage errorr (MAPE). The distributions of the percentages errors are furthermore heavily positively skewed for all models.

I now want to know whether the performance of the models differs significantly. However, I do not know if I should use the aggregated percentage errors of the predictions on the test set as the sample for the significance test (meaning sample size = 350,000) or the median (or mean) of the percentage errors of each fold (meaning sample size = 8). In the former, the sample size is enormous leading almost certainly to a significant result, while in the latter the sample size is extremely small.

Also, after selecting on the composition of the sample (and possibly the metric), what would be the preferred significance test?

Comment: Welcome! You can't use a significance test here because the same data you used to generate the model would be used to test the model. Use split-sample or cross- validation instead. The N=8 cross-validated folds do not count as independent samples.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Not sure if I follow your advise though. I use cross-validation like you suggested. I train my model on seven folds and predict on the left out fold. So the model does not see the test data during training. If I use the errors of the predictions on the test data I eventually get a number of predictions equal to the size of the total data set. If significance testing is not possible, how should I then conclude whether the performances are (most likely) different or not?

Comment: The errors-of-predictions are only going to favor models that generate wider errors, even a perfect model will be wrong 90% of the time using a 10% $\alpha$-level. So don't use that approach. Use your model validation statistics from each of the CV tests and just pick the model that's higher. If they flip-flop, then that means you have equivocal model performance: just pick the one with optimal BIC and be done with it. At the end of the day it made no difference. If you did 50,000 CV-folds and found a 0.00001 RMSE diff (p <0.05) favoring the NN model, I would say, "So what?"